# How to upload and download a directory from FTP server in java?

Tags: java

I am working in a project in which is is require to upload and download a directory and their all the file and folder in java .and I also need to know that uploding and downloading status means how much percent the folder to which I am uploading has been uploaded or downloaded.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look at the [FTPClient](http://commons.apache.org/net/api/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html) class of commons-net as well.

Answer (score 0):

A search for "java ftp client" on google reveals [edtFTPj](http://java-source.net/open-source/network-clients/edtftpj).

Answer (score 0):

Just to throw one more library at you... you could also try [Apache Commons VFS](http://commons.apache.org/vfs/filesystems.html). It gives you access to tons of different file systems including FTP.